# Two domains with same name different tld? Apache VirtualHosts

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04, virtualhost

So I am following the Ubuntu default style of [hosting domains on a LAMP server](https://askubuntu.com/a/389785/372069), and as per widely available knowledge, For each domain to be hosted,  I have to create a file with same name but with `.conf` as the extension, inside the following directory.

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available
```

So if I have to host `example.com` I will be creating a file `example.conf` with all the Apache directives for that specific domain. So far so good, now if I have to host an additional domain with same name but a different extension, say `example.org` what should I do?

One solution that is occurring to me is add the virtual host config to that same file beneath the previous code, so is this the way to go or is there any "correct" way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create your virtual host with the fqdn, eg, example.com.conf and example.org.conf

Comment: For future googlers if you are moving a site configured with `.conf` to `.[extension].conf` remember to first disable the previous conf by issuing `a2dissite xyz.conf`.